# Entry of $1-9$ in magic box

Tags: number-theory

[image]

There are 9 slots to fill. Question ask us to fill it using $1-9$ each being used only once.

But what I can see here is that $5th$ column must be filled with $1,2$ and $3$ but after $1,2$ and $3$ are used, there is no way we can satisfy $3rd$ column with $4,5,6,7,8,9$. Could someone suggest a potential solution here.

Comment: Didn't you just show that it is impossible? Check if the question actually asks to do it or simply to show whether it can be done.

Comment: I agree, there is no solution and you gave a good argument that proves that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have already pointed out, no solution exists by using each digit only once. But without the constraint, solution can be achieved.

Note that Row $5$ in first column can only take $9$ as entry and entries of column $5$ must be $1,2$ and $3$. After that just use bit of hit and trial.

[image]